# Recommended method for quickly creating a dynamic programmable php-mysql blog?

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

I want to create a blog-like website. At the begining I'll need a simple one person blog software, but in the future I'd like to have full access to the code and database (control the way posts are organized, offer special forms for creating new posts, allow users to register, implement a rating system, etc.)

What's the best solution for this? Is there a specific tool that will generate a database and php files, to which I'll have access, or should I code everything from zip?

I know Wordpress and Joomla are good blogging tools, but couldn't figure out whether I'll be able to freely redesign a blog that was created using those tools.

Comment: Wordpress and Joomla are open source - you have full access to the code. You can do whatever you want with the code, but you need a knoweledge about php and batabase.

Comment: Also you might look into Concrete 5. I evaluated it recently and found that there is a great deal of look & feel control, it's easy to setup & use, & it looks really nice.
But you won't go wrong with WordPress either... haven't used Joomla & have heard good about it but also bad (if you wan't to customize the look & feel...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is an open-source, flexible website infrastructure that is pluggable; and also quite simple to setup without any code modifications. It will generate its own database files and is capable of upgrading itself with minimal administrative overhead.

If you choose at a later date to expand the blog, you can manipulate and customize the theme (100% of what the end-users see), as you see fit.

Wordpress also has a strong plugin repository that may provide extended functionality without any need to code. For example, a post rating plugin already exists that shouldn't require coding to implement;

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rate-this-page-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Just install wordpress, you'll have full access to the code and database, and it supports writing plugins to extend functionality. You can change page layout with their template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a blog from scratch is not a simple job
Just use Wordpress for now.
There are plenty of plugins to customize Wordpress
You can later develop your own plugins or write a new weblog system and migrate to it.
I'll promise when getting familiar with Wordpress. you won't leave it anymore!